# When is OWIN startup Configuration method being called

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a web api with OWIN published on Azure as a WebApp.

Also, in the Configuration method of Startup class I do some registration part (calling another api to register the service).

The problem is that I'd want for that function to be called each time I start the WebApp in Azure Portal? Is this actually happening?

When this method is being called in relationship with Azure Start/Stop/Restart?

Comment: Those actions in Azure portal are associated with IIS level application start/stop/restart, which should have nothing to do with your StartUp class. That class is only called when an actual request arrives for the first time and ASP.NET runtime is loaded by IIS worker process.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for clarification. 
Can you suggest me a way to execute a function when the application is alive (sort of)?